# .htaccess "No input File Specified " error

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

http://pastebin.com/Uy1HZxeP

showing the error for 404 page " No input file specified "

Im not able to post it here because its showing the error called " Enter code here "

Comment: are you using any framework and when error shows what you are trying to do?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think you are using go daddy hosting for codeignitor.here is the solution.paste it in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: This is a most common error in codeignitor when hosted on Godaddy server

Comment: If you are not sure, you can ask the OP in the comments part under the question.

Comment: #Venkata Krishna #Rakesh Sharmasir few errors are common.they dont need clarification